# $route(to, from) inside watch is not working in ie

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuex

The below $route(to, from) is not working in ie-11 browser in vuejs...

```
watch: {
     $route(to, from) {
      console.log(to.query.text, "Query text");
     }
    }
```

Basically I want access the route/url parameters inside watch. It is working all the browser except ie-11

TIA..

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this Github issue:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1849

Following fix is suggested:

```
let app = {
data: function () {
},
methods: {

},
mounted () {

},
created() {
    if ('-ms-scroll-limit' in document.documentElement.style 
        && '-ms-ime-align' in document.documentElement.style) { // detect it's IE11
        window.addEventListener("hashchange", (event) => {
            var currentPath = window.location.hash.slice(1);
            if (this.$route.path !== currentPath) {
                this.$router.push(currentPath)
            }
        }, false)
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score -1):

You  need to install and import babel-polyfill in your Vue app in order to fix most of vueJs issues in IE.  Polyfill is used to provide modern functionality on browsers like IE.